# Rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Java script and coding. I am trying to figure out a syntax error in Rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock which is messing up my code. When I compile the code it says "SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" and I can't figure out why and where I messed up. Thanks for the help!

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
    var computerChoice = Math.random();
    if (computerChoice <= 0.20) {
        computerChoice = "rock";
    }
    else if (computerChoice <= 0.40) {
        computerChoice = "paper";
    }
    else if (computerChoice <= 0.60) {
        computerChoice = "scissors";
    }
    else if (computerChoice <= 0.80) {
        computerChoice = "lizard";
    }
    else {
        computerChoice = "spock";
    }
    console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
    var compare = function (choice1, choice2) {
        if (choice1 === choice2) {
            return "The result is a tie!";
        }
        else if (choice1 === "rock") {
            if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "paper wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else {
                return "spock wins";
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "paper") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "paper wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "scissors win";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
                return "lizard wins";
            }
            else {
                return "paper wins";
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "scissors win";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "lizard") {
                return "scissors win";
            }
            else {
                return "spock wins";
            }
        }
        else if (choice1 === "lizard") {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "rock wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "scissors win";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "lizard wins";
            }
            else {
                return "lizard wins";
            }
        }
        else {
            if (choice2 === "rock") {
                return "spock wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "paper") {
                return "paper wins";
            }
            else if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                return "spock nigga wins";
            }
            else {
                return "lizard wins";
            }
        }
    };
    compare(userChoice, computerChoice);
```

Comment: This question is better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. After moving it there, you need to clarify what you mean by "compiling" as JavaScript is usually interpreted. Also, most error messages include a line number for where the syntax error has occurred.

Comment: Why is your second last return `return "spock nigga wins";`?

Comment: You missed  curly brace so,go through with code and find it.I think  syntax errors not a big deal to find out yourself.

Comment: @OozeMeister Code Review is *not* a place for code which doesn't even run. Such questions are explicitly off-topic there.

Comment: Here's a very succinct implementation of rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock in JavaScript with a playable demo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17761388/783743

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a closing parenthesis : 
`else if (choice2 === "scissors"`

Comment: May I ask the reason of the downvote?